# Issues Installing dual-boot disks on a new Dell G5 desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a 1TB SSD that I removed from my work desktop and wanted to install in my new Dell G5 desktop in another location. I tested booting using that disk to both Ubuntu (16.04) and Windows 10 from the grub menu at my home desktop, but with the new desktop I can only boot into windows.

I did make sure to follow the instructions on Dell's page "Ensure the BIOS is set to UEFI, disable Legacy option ROMS and disable the secure boot." Also I did remove the 500Gb drive that came with the PC to be sure the only boot partitions available are on the dual boot disk I'm installing.

Any ideas on how to make the G5 boot to the Ubuntu grub boot selection window? I'm guessing I missed one of the settings in BIOS to enable that.

Steve

Comment: check also windows' fast start

Comment: If a new Dell, your 16.04 may be too old. Most new systems need the newest kernel, driver & support software. A few are so new you have to add even a newer kernel than is in most current distribution. Dell has some unique drivers in its Sputnik, but normally adds those to Linux distributions. But that takes some time. Did you have nVidia driver with old system? If not you may need nomodeset boot  parameter. Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. And are drives set to AHCI, not RAID, nor Intel RST?